# Maximum "outdegree of a level" inside a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a connected undirected graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and some vertex $v$ with eccentricity $e_v\geq 2$, I want to know the maximum possible number of edges respect to n that connects vertices at a distance $d\geq 1$ (from $v$) to vertices at a distance $d+1$ (from $v$). I call it the "outdegree" of the "level" $d$ (respect to $v$).

- I know (or guess) that such max "outdegree" happens when the connections between levels $d$ and $d+1$ forms a complete bipartite graph, so the maximum number of edges would be $xy$ if $x$ is the order of the level $d$ and $y$ the order of the level $d+1$.
- Since such "outdegree" can't be bigger than the total number of edges, $xy\leq n(n-1)/2$, but since $x$ is at distance $d\geq 1$, there is at least one "indegree" edge at level $d$, so $xy\lt n(n-1)/2$.
- Also, $1\leq x,y$ and $x+y\lt n$ because there's at least one node in the level $d-1$.

So far I have the following optimization problem:
$$
s^*=\max xy,\quad xy\lt n(n-1)/2,\quad x+y\lt n,\quad x,y\in\mathbb{N}^{\geq1}
$$

No idea about how to solve it and express the solution $s^*$ in terms of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can be more precise: if we are bounding the number of edges between level $d$ and level $d+1$, then $x + y$ can be at most $n-d$: there must be at least one vertex at levels $0, 1, 2, \dots, d-1$, leaving $n-d$ vertices at levels $d$ and $d+1$.

For a fixed sum $x+y$, the product $xy$ is maximized when $x$ and $y$ are as equal as possible. (By the AM-GM inequality, $\frac{x+y}{2} \ge \sqrt{xy}$ - $xy$ is at most $\frac{(x+y)^2}{4}$, which is achieved when $x$ and $y$ are each equal to $\frac{x+y}{2}$.)

So we get the most edges when there is only $1$ vertex at levels $0$ through $d-1$, then $\frac{n-d}{2}$ vertices at level $d$ and $\frac{n-d}{2}$ vertices at level $d+1$. This gives us $\frac{(n-d)^2}{4}$ edges.

(In case $n-d$ is odd, the optimal solution sets one of $x,y$ to $\frac{n-d+1}{2}$ and the other to $\frac{n-d-1}{2}$, for an optimal value of $\frac{(n-d)^2-1}{4}$, which just so happens to be $\lfloor \frac{(n-d)^2}{4}\rfloor$.)

Comment: $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ so I think you have to check whether $n-d$ is odd or even, and in case of odd, checking whether setting $x$ as the ceil or the floor of the division (and assigning $y=n-d-x$) gives a bigger value. Also, if you add $d$, then I guess you have to make sure that $xy\leq n(n-1)/2 - d$.

Comment: You are right about odd, but we don't care about which is ceiling and which is floor (because $xy = yx$). Also, we don't have to make sure $xy$ is at most $n(n-1)/2-d$: because we have a concrete graph we're describing here, it will automatically have at most the maximum number of edges it can have.

Comment: About the $n(n-1)/2-d$ bound, it's right the graph must to be correct, but anyway I've realized, by plotting the inequations in desmos.com, that if $x+y<=n-d$, then $xy<=n(n-1)/2-d$ (at least when the other restrictions also happens: $x,y\leq 1$, $1\leq d<=n-2$ and $n\geq 3$), but I haven't been able to prove it.

Comment: Another observation; at levels $d$ and $d+1$ there's $n-d$ nodes only when $d+1$ is the last level of a BFS search. Your answer is not taking into account the nodes at levels beyond $d+1$. Actually, the maximum number of nodes at levels $d$ and $d+1$ of a graph with $d^* + 1$ levels would be $n-((d^*+1)-2)=n-d^*+1$ ($-2$ stands for the two levels we are measuring) regardless of what $d$ is, which in turn is maximized when $d^*=\text{diam}(G)$, which in turn is maximized when $\text{diam}(G)=2$, which is our minimum requirement, so $n-1$. Isn't it?

Comment: Why would you have more than $d+1$ levels? That would be unnecessarily limiting the number of edges between levels $d$ and $d+1$ that you could achieve.

Comment: Because we didn't specify at which level we were at. But yes, we can assume the d+1 level is the last one, because that doesn't change how many vertices we are substracting.